# django CSS & Javascript not loading in HTML files?, error 404?

Tags: django

I have put some static files for CSS Javascript and Jquery in my file static.
I have put load static in my HTML and it doesn't respond properly to the HTML.
Do you have anything else to do with it?
[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM3Le.png) 
[setting.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RezYD.png)

Comment: What's your `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: my  parameters for it in setting.py 
 STATIC_URL = '/static'

Comment: rewrite href of line 11 in index.html to `href="{% static 'menu/Acceuil.css' %}"` be careful that between % and } must be no space

Comment: thanks ,  i didn't know it matters

Comment: what about a link for an image in the tag src=" {% static 'images/tlchargement1.png' %}"
if the image is in folder images that is located in the folder static?

Comment: I have no idea about this. check the source code of loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have not added `/static/` urls to your `urls.py` and set `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings equal to path to your static files:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

You can see it in docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development